# Reset frame number and total frame count per Beamer section

Tags: beamer, sectioning, page-numbering

I'm using a LaTeX Beamer frame counter that displays

```
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
```

... which would mean that if my project has twenty frames and the slideshow is on the sixteenth frame, *"16/20"* is displayed.

My project contains very long sections (they mirror book chapters), and I want the *frames of each section to have a counter local to that section*.

For example, if that sixteenth frame is actually in section 2, and section 1 had 5 frames, then it should show *"11/15"*.

Maybe there's a solution with `\AtBeginSection`, but I doubt it, since there would be no good way of calculating `\inserttotalframenumber` to my knowledge.

If it helps, here's an MWE of my current setup (with fewer frames):

```
%%% Preamble %%%
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usebeamercolor{dolphin}

% Make slide numbers appear, and they appear next to navigation
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

%%% Document %%%
\begin{document}

    \section{First section}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First}
        This frame should show ``1/2'', not ``1/5''.
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Second}
        This frame should show ``2/2'', not ``2/5''.
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Second section}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Third}
        This frame should show ``1/3'', not ``3/5''.
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Fourth}
        This frame should show ``2/3'', not ``4/5''.
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Fifth}
        This frame should show ``3/3'', not ``5/5''.
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would really help the community if you could provide us with a complete, minimal example that replicates your current setup. Something with a couple of sections with different frame counts. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner I have added the bare minimum setup below the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach inserts a "label" into the `.aux` at every `\section` (including at the end of the document) in order to capture the current frame number. This captured frame number (which resets with every `\section` thanks to [`chngcntr`](//ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr)) is then inserted in the footer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usebeamercolor{dolphin}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{framenumber}{section}% Number frames within \section

% Make slide numbers appear, and they appear next to navigation
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
  \usebeamerfont{footline}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \hspace{1em}%
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumberbysection
}

\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{% Store current \section's frame count
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\global\noexpand\@namedef{s@totalsectionframes-\arabic{section}}{\arabic{framenumber}}}%
  \oldsection
}
\AtEndDocument{% Store final \section's frame count
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\global\noexpand\@namedef{s@totalsectionframes-\arabic{section}}{\arabic{framenumber}}}%
}
\newcommand{\inserttotalframenumberbysection}{\csname s@totalsectionframes-\arabic{section}\endcsname}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First}
  This frame shows ``1/2'', not ``1/5''.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second}
  This frame shows ``2/2'', not ``2/5''.
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Third}
  This frame shows ``1/3'', not ``3/5''.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Fourth}
  This frame shows ``2/3'', not ``4/5''.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Fifth}
  This frame shows ``3/3'', not ``5/5''.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's kind of baffling to me that you had to put in non-trivial work to do this, as I'd expect Beamer to just have this built in. Great work.

Comment: @Mew: The total frame number count is just a label that is stored at the end of the document. So in order to capture the per-section frame total you have to flex some other muscles. I'm sure there might be a more [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer)-ish way, but my approach seems to work as expected.